# Post slugs colliding with page links php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a music blog and using htaccess for url rewriting but am having issues with page links colliding with artist links coz i want the artist link to be like https://eachamps.com/artistname. But am in a situation where even page links like http://eachamps.com/audios are being seen as artist links.
A solution to my problem shall be highly appreciated

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ artist.php?artist=$1 [L]
```

I want to stop the collision between the page links and post slugs

Comment: Well you can use a separate Rewrite rule for the audio page

Comment: Could you Please show me how?

Comment: Try this code `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/audio`. Add this before the first RewriteRule